# Copy dependent projects needed files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, orchardcms, projects-and-solutions, project-structure

I have a sample project that is structured like the below image:

[image: Project struct]

The WebApplication2 has depended on ClassLibrary1 at publishing time like this:

[image]

I want to copy some needed file in ClassLibrary1 project after publishing in a specific folder, for example in Plug-in/ClassLibrary1/
If you've looked at [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net) you'd see something like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general (regardless of the type of the application) you could define custom actions during deployment, if you build a setup application. I think that [limited edition of the InstallShield](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/15/what-s-new-in-visual-studio-2013-and-installshield-limited-edition.aspx) is the default solution for VS2013. There you could create some [custom actions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQWhaTh9EdI) writing a script. Inside this script you could deploy the specific file. An alternative against the InstallShield is the [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) which you could use to build an MSI file using an XML.

Regarding web applications in particular, you could use the [publish mechanism provided by the Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) describes how you could configure it so that it would copy all project files. Then you could add the specific file as a project file and copy it each time you publish your website.

Hope I helped!

Comment: thanks :), but my problem is something  else. My project is a web application and I want to copy required files on building or publishing.